# Three.js DirectionalLightHelper when light is attached to camera

Tags: 3d, camera, three.js, light

I am trying to use the DirectionalLightHelper when my directional light is attached to the camera. I am attaching the light to the camera in order to simulate the scene spinning when using the TrackballControls.

```
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.5 ); 
directionalLight.position.set( 100, 100, 0 ); 

camera.add( directionalLight );

directionalLightHelper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(directionalLight, 50); 
camera.add( directionalLightHelper);
```

However, this doesn't give me the expected results. If I move the camera around a bit using the TrackballControls I do eventually 'find' the light plane and target line rendered by the helper but they are not in the correct place. I would expect the plane to be centered at 0,0,0 facing the light source and the the line to be going from 100,100,0 through 0,0,0. Am I misunderstanding something here or is there something more I need to do when using the helper with the light attached to the camera?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the light helper to the *scene,* rather than to the camera.

Comment: This still doesn't do it for me. The light plane is now much larger but is still floating around somewhere, seemingly randomly. The only thing I have found that seems to put everything in the correct place is to comment out the following line in DirectionalLightHelper.js:

    this.matrix = light.matrixWorld;

Not sure why this should be the case though?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the light is follow the camera coordinates, not the world ones.

Comment: could be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem when attaching the directionalLight to the camera. Instead of also attaching my directionalLightHelper to the camera, I had to attach it to the scene.

```
scene.add(directionalLightHelper);
```

Then I had to add the following to my render loop to properly update the helper as my light changed position.

```
directionalLight.updateMatrixWorld();
directionalLightHelper.position.setFromMatrixPosition(directionalLight.matrixWorld);
directionalLightHelper.updateMatrix();
directionalLightHelper.update();
```

---

EDIT:

codepen of broken helper https://codepen.io/briantjacobs/pen/dRNJpw 
codepen of working helper https://codepen.io/briantjacobs/pen/VWProE